# Android Studio error "requires libraries and applications that depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the Android APIs."

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, gradle, mobile

All libraries are updated.

**Library versions:**

```kotlin
implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation-experimental:1.3.0'
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.9.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.6'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config-ktx:21.1.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:21.1.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
implementation 'com.github.denzcoskun:ImageSlideshow:0.1.0'
implementation("com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1")
```

**Error:**

> 3 issues were found when checking AAR metadata:
>
> 1. Dependency 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0' requires libraries and applications that depend on it to compile against version 33 or later
>    of the Android APIs. :app is currently compiled against android-32.
>
>    Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer
>    compileSdkVersion of at least 33, for example 33.   Note that updating
>    a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which allows newer APIs
>    to be used) can be done separately from updating targetSdkVersion
>    (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and minSdkVersion
>    (which determines which devices the app can be installed on).
> 2. Dependency 'androidx.core:core:1.9.0' requires libraries and applications that depend on it to compile against version 33 or later
>    of the Android APIs.    :app is currently compiled against android-32.
>
>    Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer
>    compileSdkVersion of at least 33, for example 33.     Note that
>    updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which allows
>    newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
>    targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
>    minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
>    on).
> 3. Dependency 'androidx.annotation:annotation-experimental:1.3.0' requires libraries and applications that depend on it to compile
>    against version 33 or later of the Android APIs. :app is currently
>    compiled against android-32.
>
>    Recommended action: Update this project
>    to use a newer compileSdkVersion of at least 33, for example 33. Note
>    that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
>    allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
>    targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
>    minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
>    on).

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

There are two ways to fix this error:

1. Increase `compileSdk`, `targetSdk` values from `32` to `33` in `build.gradle` file (app level).
2. (Not recommended) Decrease dependencies in `build.gradle` to old values:

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0' 
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.0'
```

After these changes - resync the project with Gradle files.

But it is best to use the *first* way, as it is necessary to support [Android 13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_13).

Comment: You don't need to update the target SDK at all - just updating the compile SDK is enough - that's why the error specifically only mentions compile SDK. Target SDK can be changed much later

Comment: Thanks, changing the compileSdk and targetSdk worked for me.

Answer (score 11):

Change your compileSdk 32 to 33 from build.gradle (Module)

```
android {
compileSdk 33

defaultConfig {
    ..
    minSdk 24
    targetSdk 33
    ..
}}
```

Comment: This YouTube video explains how to do it, I had to look it up - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=17UD6rp222k

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem. When I change back the libraries it's working fine

```
 implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

When I change back the libraries it's working fine

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

These warnings indicate that you're currently compiling your application with Android API version 32, while the libraries you're using in your project require at least API version 33. This could cause runtime issues or even prevent your app from running properly.

Here's how you can fix this issue:

Open your build.gradle file (the one that is in your app module, not the root one).
Locate the line compileSdkVersion and change the value to at least 33.
Similarly, if you want to opt into new runtime behaviour, you could also update the targetSdkVersion to 33. Note that this could change the behaviour of your app due to changes in permissions, lifecycle, etc., so you may need to update your code to handle these changes.
If you want to ensure your app can still be installed on older devices, do not change the minSdkVersion.
Here's how the relevant part of your build.gradle file should look after making these changes:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 33

    // if you also want to update the target version
    targetSdkVersion 33
    
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.yourapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    // Rest of your configuration...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just open the file "bulid.gradle.kts(Module.app)"
and replace all 33 with 34 and then sync
`compileSdk 34`
`targetSdk 34`

Comment: strange, negative voices are visible and positive ones are not visible, hmmmm

Answer (score 0):

in my case, i have one module of type android librari, when i launch my task of jacoco i get the following error(Dependency 'androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.8.0' requires libraries and applications that
depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
Android APIs.

```
       :feedback is currently compiled against android-33.

       Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle
       plugin 8.1.0 is 33.

       Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle
       plugin to one that supports 34, then update this project to use
       compileSdk of at least 34.

       Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
       allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
       targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
       minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
       on).

   2.  Dependency 'androidx.activity:activity:1.8.0' requires libraries and applications that
       depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
       Android APIs.

       :feedback is currently compiled against android-33.

       Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle
       plugin 8.1.0 is 33.

       Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle
       plugin to one that supports 34, then update this project to use
       compileSdk of at least 34.

       Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
       allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
       targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
       minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
       on).

   3.  Dependency 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.0' requires libraries and applications that
       depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
       Android APIs.

       :feedback is currently compiled against android-33.

       Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle
       plugin 8.1.0 is 33.

       Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle
       plugin to one that supports 34, then update this project to use
       compileSdk of at least 34.

       Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
       allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
       targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
       minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
       on).
```

).

Apparently the dependency "com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0" in the gradle of my module was implicitly giving me a version of "androidx.activity:activity-ktx" which is not compatible with my target sdk, the solution to my problem was remove that dependency

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, solved my issue by updating `compileSdk 33` to `compileSdk 34` and `targetSdk 33` to `targetSdk 32` in my build.gradle (:app).
Thanks to all your comments.

Answer (score -2):

For `cordova` apps: increase `<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="32" />` in `config.xml` to `<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="33" />`.