# Error after suggested update for androidx.core-ktx:1.9.0

Tags: android-studio, compiler-errors

When I follow the suggested update for `androidx.core-ktx:1.9.0` all of my code become red waved underline, and the following error occurs after compiling the project:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
```

But after reverting that update, everything runs normally. What is the reason of this unexpected incompatibility?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Increasing the targetSdk and compileSdk to level 33 solved the problem for me.

Original answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/73688665/2077248