# Showing error while building app in android studio

Tags: android, build.gradle

[This is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NP00y.png)

I tried to update and upgrade the gradle build but it didn't work at all. So, I'm willing to get the help that how to fix it.

6 issues were found when checking AAR metadata:

1. Dependency 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.6.1' requires libraries and applications that
   depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the
   Android APIs.

   :app is currently compiled against android-32.

   Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion
   of at least 33, for example, 33.

   Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
   allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
   targetSdkVersion (which opts the app into new runtime behavior) and
   minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
   on).
2. Dependency 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1' requires libraries and applications that
   depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the
   Android APIs.

   :app is currently compiled against android-32.

   Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion
   of at least 33, for example, 33.

   Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
   allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
   targetSdkVersion (which opts the app into new runtime behavior) and
   minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
   on).
3. Dependency 'androidx.activity:activity:1.6.0' requires libraries and applications that
   depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the
   Android APIs.

   :app is currently compiled against android-32.

   Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion
   of at least 33, for example, 33.

   Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
   allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
   targetSdkVersion (which opts the app into new runtime behavior) and
   minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
   on).
4. Dependency 'androidx.core:core:1.9.0' requires libraries and applications that
   depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the
   Android APIs.

   :app is currently compiled against android-32.

   Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion
   of at least 33, for example, 33.

   Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
   allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
   targetSdkVersion (which opts the app into new runtime behavior) and
   minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
   on).
5. Dependency 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0' requires libraries and applications that
   depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the
   Android APIs.

   :app is currently compiled against android-32.

   Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion
   of at least 33, for example, 33.

   Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
   allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
   targetSdkVersion (which opts the app into new runtime behavior) and
   minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
   on).
6. Dependency 'androidx.annotation:annotation-experimental:1.3.0' requires libraries and applications that
   depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the
   Android APIs.

   :app is currently compiled against android-32.

   Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion
   of at least 33, for example, 33.

   Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
   allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
   targetSdkVersion (which opts the app into new runtime behavior) and
   minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
   on).

Comment: Did you even try reading the error? Your app is being compiled using `compileSdkVersion` 32 while you should be using 33.

Answer (score 0):

This page may be useful to you.
There is an approved answer

[Android Studio error "requires libraries and applications that depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the Android APIs."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73688486/android-studio-error-requires-libraries-and-applications-that-depend-on-it-to-c)

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0' 
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Really straightforward: your `compileSdk` version specified in your gradle file is 32. It should be increased to 33 or you should use older versions of those specified libraries. But the first approach is encouraged to do.